# Ubuntu 15.04 freezes when shutting down

Tags: shutdown

I´m having an issue with my laptop shutting down - after installing Ubuntu 15.04 when I press shut down after going into the shut-down screen it freezes, and I have to press the power switch off the laptop. Please help, as I am a new user to Ubuntu. For reference I have an HP-15 Notebook [(Manual)](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04341736.pdf) [(Specs)](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03130023)

Thanks,
Shivantha

Comment: Can you shut down by opening a terminal and typing `sudo shutdown now`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem sometimes hitting some users on some machines.

If it is a permanent issue for you - there is an alternative to shutdown a PC.

When you want to shutdown your computer open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo poweroff
```

If it is a randomly appearing problem - there is a workaround available.

When the freezing issue occurs while trying to shutdown your computer :

Perform the **Magic SysReq method** by pressing

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysReq</kbd> and while keeping it pressed -> <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>.

Do this quite slowly - wait a second between each key stroke.

Your computer will restart - you can shut it down from login screen now.